# How to compute Wilcoxon rank-sum test in Stata?

Tags: nonparametric, stata, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I would like to compute the Wilcoxon rank-sum test in Stata for two countries of my sample with the dummyvalue 3 and 6.

Can anyone give the right code for Stata?

Comment: The on-line help for `ranksum` in Stata is pretty straightforward. What do you mean precisely by "dummyvalue 3 and 6": are countries coded in separate columns, or as one column?

Answer (score 4):

Something like:
`. ranksum y if country==3 | country==6, by(country)`
or, slightly more concisely,
`. ranksum y if inlist(country,3,6), by(country)`
 (where y is the outcome variable you wish to test).